# Woocommerce Admin Product Search Not working

Tags: php, wordpress, search, woocommerce

I ran into the issue that woocommerce product search in admin not working and giving result as `No product found` though there are lots of products with my search input.

Also i haven't used `relevancy search` plugin so there will be no any issue.

I set debug true in `wp-congig.php` and its throwing one error related to wp_meta with printing whole query.

Also tried disable theme and try with default theme also tried to disable every plugin one by one but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same thing and adding the following code block to my `functions.php` file fixed it immediately:

```
function m_request_query( $query_vars ) {
    global $typenow;
    global $wpdb;
    global $pagenow;

    if ( 'product' === $typenow && isset( $_GET['s'] ) && 'edit.php' === $pagenow ) {
        $search_term  = esc_sql( sanitize_text_field( $_GET['s'] ) );
    // Split the search term by comma.
        $search_terms = explode( ',', $search_term );
    // If there are more terms make sure we also search for the whole thing, maybe it's not a list of terms.
        if ( count( $search_terms ) > 1 ) {
            $search_terms[] = $search_term;
        }
    // Cleanup the array manually to avoid issues with quote escaping.
        array_walk( $search_terms, 'trim' );
        array_walk( $search_terms, 'esc_sql' );
        $meta_key               = '_sku';
        $post_types             = array( 'product', 'product_variation' );
        $query                  = "SELECT DISTINCT posts.ID as product_id, posts.post_parent as parent_id FROM {$wpdb->posts} posts LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} AS postmeta ON posts.ID = postmeta.post_id WHERE postmeta.meta_key = '{$meta_key}' AND postmeta.meta_value IN  ('" . implode( "','", $search_terms ) . "') AND posts.post_type IN ('" . implode( "','", $post_types ) . "') ORDER BY posts.post_parent ASC, posts.post_title ASC";
        $search_results         = $wpdb->get_results( $query );
        $product_ids            = wp_parse_id_list( array_merge( wp_list_pluck( $search_results, 'product_id' ), wp_list_pluck( $search_results, 'parent_id' ) ) );
        $query_vars['post__in'] = array_merge( $product_ids, $query_vars['post__in'] );
    }

    return $query_vars;
}
add_filter( 'request', 'm_request_query', 20 );
```

Shout-out to [mircian](https://mircian.com/2018/04/06/extending-woocommerce-admin-product-search/) for the snippet.

Comment: Added benefit of being able to search for multiple SKUs separated by commas (don't include spaces, just commas). Example: 12345,ABCDEF,othersku